# Unable to make api calls in firefox because "the resource at url was blocked because content blocking is enabled"?

Tags: javascript, firefox

My app makes api call to third party app to fetch data.

However, in firefox some people get this error.

Is there a workaround or a way to fix it.

Comment: Have they installed AdBlock (or something similar) and asked to block content from the site?  If, so either you have to use another site or they have to remove the block from within AdBlock

Comment: It is part of Firefox trying to keep people more "secure". They would need to add you as trusted https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/content-blocking